# How to use online database (specially on byethost7.com) in android app for inserting information?

Tags: android, mysql, database

I am making an android project which inserts information into mysql database via php code. I am able to do so on my local server (using xampp). I have taken a free webhosting byethost7.com domain http://hpisys.byethost7.com for using my database and php file from that server. I am able to open php page on internet and insert the information into the online database server. But via android app I am not able to insert information using the same php code. Please help me out of this.

Answer (score 0):

If you are also using this data in a web project I would set up a RESTful service and get the data that way. If not I would use something like Firebase instead, as it will be much easier to set up.

Either way you will need to research those yourself. You should be able to find a lot of tutorials.